# Get array of ids from object array in firestore

Tags: arrays, typescript, object, google-cloud-firestore

in firestore I have a document with two strings and also an object array with [{email: ..., id: ..., nickname: ...} {...}]
I use a subscription to get all users from that specific document. The next step is to extract all ids from that object array (called "users") in a new array.. But I have no idea how to do this.
I try somethink like this:

this.group.forEach(element => console.log(element)

"this.group" is the subscription of that document. But this output display all content from this document and not the only array called (users)[See attachement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpgKE.png).

Hope anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop it and push it in a new array like this. See sample code below:

```
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

    const newArray = [];

    if (docSnap.exists()) {
      const users = docSnap.data().users
      users.forEach(element => {
        newArray.push(element.id);
      })

      // This will return an array of `id` from the `users` array.
      console.log(newArray);
    } else {
      // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
      console.log("No such document!");
    }
```

The same logic will be applied if you use it to the subscription of the document.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Marc! I understand that logic. I just have a problem with docSnap.. I get the data with Angular Firestore. How to change the part "await getDoc(docRef) to an "angular-friendly-logic"? This is my query in service.ts:  
groupUser(): Observable<any[]> {
    const groupId = this.router.url.split('/').pop();
    return this.afStore.collection('Group', id => id.where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', groupId)).valueChanges()
  }
and in group.ts:
this.group = this.groupService.groupUser();